# hiding console window LNK4044 warning

Tags: windows, compiler-construction, console, warnings, scons

I'm using scons to compile my C++ app disabling console window but I can't get this done.
Searching in the internet, and in StackOverflow, I found that this line would work
`env.Append( LINKFLAGS=['-Wl,-subsystem,windows'] )`
The problem is I always receive a warning message that this line is ignored.
This is the message:

`LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/Wl,-subsystem,windows'; ignored`

I've already tried:
`env.Append( LINKFLAGS=['-Wl,-subsystem:windows'] )`
`env.Append( LINKFLAGS='-Wl,-subsystem,windows' )`
`env.Append( LINKFLAGS=['/Wl,-subsystem,windows'] )`
`env.Append( LINKFLAGS=['/Wl,-subsystem:windows'] )`
Like you noticed, many possibilities I've done, but no sucess.
Below I post some part of my SConstruct file.
Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks for all replies

```
# GNU GCC
if 'gcc' in env[ 'compiler' ]:
env.Append( CCFLAGS='-Wall', CPPDEFINES=['GCC'] )
if int( debug ):
    env.Append( CCFLAGS='-g', LINKFLAGS='-g' )
else:
    env.Append( CCFLAGS='-O2', LINKFLAGS='-O2' )`
# MSVC v9 
elif 'msvc' in env['compiler']:
env.Append( LINKCOM=[ 'mt.exe -nologo -manifest ${TARGET}.manifest -outputresource:$TARGET;1' ] )
env.Append( SHLINKCOM=[ 'mt.exe -nologo -manifest ${TARGET}.manifest -outputresource:$TARGET;2' ] )
env.Append( CCFLAGS='/W3 /EHsc', CPPDEFINES=[ 'WIN32', 'WINDOWS', 'MSVC', '_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS' ] )
env.Append( CPPDEFINES='MSVC_DLL' )
env.Append( LIBS = 'WS2_32' )
env.AppendUnique( LINKFLAGS=['-Wl,-subsystem,windows'] )

if int( debug ):
    env.Append( CCFLAGS='/Od /RTC1 /MDd /Gy /Zi', LINKFLAGS='/DEBUG' )
else:
    env.Append( CCFLAGS='/O2 /Oi /GL /MD', LINKFLAGS='/LTCG')`
```

Comment: wl seems to be a compiler flag used to set warning levels; at least it is not documented as being a linker flag.  Since you are already setting warning levels in your CCFLAGS, just get rid of the "wl".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys. I've made a mistake.
Wl, is just for supress warnings;
Like you said: it's just to insert `env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['/Wl', '/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS'])` in the SConstruct.
I've made a very dummy mistake.
In the main.cpp I forgot to do a simple verification of if I running my software on a console or on a windowed app. 
Just a simple #ifdef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

thanks for you support.

Answer (score 0):

env.Append(LINKFLAGS=['/Wl', '/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS'])

not sure if its case sensitive but that should work. Your options just aren't getting fed to the linker right it seems.

Comment: Also I agree with Luke that the Wl is a little suspect for the linker... but at any rate if you want to pass multiple flags to the linker in one line, use quoted, comma separated lists like above and it should be good to go